# Interaction of the same smooth variable with two factors in mgcv

Tags: r, mgcv

I am not sure how to formulate the following model in `mgcv`:

```
FactorA*s( Smooth ) + FactorB*s( Smooth )
```

This is

```
FactorA + FactorB + FactorA:s( Smooth ) + FactorB:s( Smooth )
```

(i.e. this is not a three-way interaction, because `FactorA:FactorB:Smooth` is not present).

My best guess is

```
s( Smooth, by = FactorA ) + FactorA + s( Smooth, by = FactorB ) + FactorB
```

but I'm really not sure.

Motivation: I am trying to reproduce

```
N ~ DOW + Year + rcs( DOY ) + SEX*rcs( AgeCut ) + DOW:rcs( AgeCut ), offset = log( Population )
```

(N is the number of cases from a disease, DOW is day-of-week, DOY is day-of-year) from the `rms` package where `rcs` stands for restricted cubic spline extension.

Except for the last term, my solution was

```
N ~ DOW + Year + s( DOY, bs = "cc" ) + SEX + s( AgeCut, by = SEX )
```

but I got stuck with the `DOW:rcs( AgeCut )` interaction.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, but this still seems to be primarily a question about how to specify something for an R function, essentially a programming question.

Comment: @Glen_b : Actually it does have statistical considerations (as confirmed by Simon Wood in email), but right now he can't post this as an answer...

Comment: I think that ordered factors are what is needed here. From reading `?gam.models` a little more closely, I wonder if the following is what is required: `N ~ DOW + SEX + Year + s( DOY, bs = "cc" ) + s( AgeCut), s(AgeCut, by = SEX ) + s(AgeCut, by = DOW)` where `DOW` and `SEX` have been converted to ordered factors. The intercept would represent the reference levels of DOW and SEX with the `s(AgeCut)`  also referring to that combo. Then the two `by` smoothers represent smooth *differences* btw that reference combo and the other levels of `SEX` or `DOW`.

Comment: @GavinSimpson : Yes, that was one of the solutions Simon Wood suggested! I am really wondering if there is any way to re-open this question, so that he can post his remarks as an answer. Which would of course also prove that this is not off-topic... But right now it seems to be a Catch-22...

Comment: Beyond voting to reopen (this has 2 reopen votes currently, one of them mine) your option would only be to flag the question for Moderator attention, making your case in the "Other" reason for flagging, or post on [CV Meta](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/) and explain why you feel this is a statistical issue. The latter may get the question some attention by people with reopen privileges, which might boost the reopen voting.

Comment: Thanks for the flag. I'm sure we can get this re-opened, but it does need a little more explanation of what the statistical issue is - what model does `FactorA*s( Smooth ) + FactorB*s( Smooth )` represent (in English & Maths)?